# How to manage changing account balance in a react native app

Tags: react-native

I am a newbie react native developper working on fintech app. The app basically does transactions and the user should see its balance. But here comes the problem, I cannot update its balance according to transactions because it is not updated automatically but he has to disconnect and then reconnect in order to see the reel balance.
I've tried using async storage, secure store but it doesn't actually work. And also I've heard that redux would help me but I don't really get it to work.
Any help would help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try refreshing / re-fetching the data after every transaction done by the app and update it

Comment: @HOSENUR thank you for your response. It's a great idea but how can I do that seeing that my user data is stored in SecureStore. Could you please be more explicit?